# Python/Regex - get start/end date and time from a string?

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to extract the start date and time and the end date and time from this string, but have no idea how to do it, my first though was to find "Start Time & Date" and then get the next 20 chars from this point and try convert them to dates and times after, but im presuming there is a better way to do this?

```
body = """
Dear Customer,

Details of service affected:

Start Time & Date: 02/12/2016 02:00   
Completion Time & Date: 02/12/2016 06:00    

Details of Work:
Change faulty card
"""
if "Start Time & Date" in body:
    #get next 20 chars?
```

Comment: You only need to get the next 16 characters.

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? If the template is constant it's fine.

Comment: Use `re.findall('\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}', body)`

Comment: sorry  @ettanany didn't see your comment should i remove my answer?

Comment: @ettanany works a dream! do you want to post this as the answer so i can accept? thanks

Comment: @nick_gabpe you should NOT remove your answer. I added an answer before and people start to downvote and I can not understand why, so that's why I moved it to comments!

Comment: @AlexW I just undeleted my answer, do not forget to upvote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> re.findall('\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}', body)
['02/12/2016 02:00', '02/12/2016 06:00']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
body = """
Dear Customer,

Details of service affected:

Start Time & Date: 02/12/2016 02:00   
Completion Time & Date: 02/12/2016 06:00    

Details of Work:
Change faulty card
"""
my_time = re.search(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}', body)
print (my_time.group())
```

Comment: You have two '=' sign, please fix it